# QT crashes when trying to change a string from a class

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Here are my scripts:

```
void FileOperations::SetInputFile(QString x){
    InputFilename=x.toStdString();
}
void FileOperations::SetOutputFile(QString x){
    OutputFilename=x.toStdString();
}
```

The first one (SetInputFile) crashes when trying to set InputFilename to x.
The second one works fine.

Here is the class that i am changing those two strings from:

```
class FileOperations
{
public:
    void SetInputFile(QString x);
    void SetOutputFile(QString x);
private:
    string InputFilename;
    string OutputFilename;
};
```

As you can see, 'InputFilename' and 'OutputFilename' are identical, and their functions are almost identical also.
I tried changing the strings to different names, but it still crashes.

After it crashes I can press debug, and view the errors in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, here is the crash info:

> msvcr100d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData)  Line 52 + 0x3 bytes    C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!std::allocator::deallocate(char * _Ptr, unsigned int __formal)  Line 182 + 0x9 bytes C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!std::basic_string,std::allocator >::_Tidy(bool _Built, unsigned int _Newsize)  Line 1998 C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!std::basic_string,std::allocator >::assign(std::basic_string,std::allocator > && _Right)  Line 722 C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!std::basic_string,std::allocator >::operator=(std::basic_string,std::allocator > && _Right)  Line 710  C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!FileOperations::SetInputFile(QString x)  Line 8 + 0x26 bytes   C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!MainWindow::on_OpenButton_clicked()  Line 20   C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(QObject * _o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a)  Line 72 + 0x8 bytes  C++
>       ShitLEncoder.exe!MainWindow::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void * * _a)  Line 106 + 0x15 bytes C++
>       Qt5Cored.dll!615820e0()
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for Qt5Cored.dll]
>       Qt5Cored.dll!615c613f()
>       Qt5Cored.dll!615c5ac1()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!66a7118b()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!66727087()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6672703b()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!66728092()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!66629ef5()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!66624c40()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!665e0887()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!66625405()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!6665de30()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!665f15a0()
>       Qt5Widgetsd.dll!665e0253()
>       msvcr100d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData, int nBlockUse)  Line 1267 + 0xc bytes C++
>       0246b188()

The first thing it shows in code is:

```
_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));
```

I am using QT 5 with the QT Creator.

[EDIT]
Here is the code that the QT mainwindow class uses to call those functions:

```
void MainWindow::on_OpenButton_clicked()
{
    ui->OpenText->setText(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),"",tr("Any                               file")));
    FileController->SetInputFile(ui->OpenText->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_SaveButton_clicked()
{
    ui->SaveText->setText(QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save File"),"",tr("Any     file")));
    FileController->SetOutputFile(ui->SaveText->text());
}
```

Comment: Is FileOperations in another folder than mainwindow, found via INCLUDEPATH?

Comment: FileOperations is a separate class, but it's not in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it, I'm unsure how this worked, I changed this:

```
class FileOperations
{
public:
    void SetInputFile(QString x);
    void SetOutputFile(QString x);
private:
    string InputFilename;
    string OutputFilename;
};
```

To this:

```
class FileOperations
{
public:
    void SetInputFile(QString x);
    void SetOutputFile(QString x);
private:
    string UnusedVariable;
    string InputFilename;
    string OutputFilename;
};
```

I add an extra unused variable, and it stops the crash :D

Comment: So you still have the issue. What you have provided is not a solution.

Comment: If that "fixed" it, you may have just needed a full clean and build.

Comment: clean and build, like a rebuild? well if that's what you mean, I tried that many times o.o
And I modified other things to get it to work, which didn't help.

@Kamil Klimek
Well what provided fixed my problem, sorta making it a solution.. i guess :S

Comment: IF i remove the unused variable now, it still screws up the program.
@Kamil Klimek

Comment: C++ does not work like that, so if it fixed then it's possible that something much worse will come out later in your code. Where do you allocate FileController. Show us more code because with current context we can't see where did you make mistake

Comment: Ok, I've pasted all my code. http://pastebin.com/RTfEZQdD 
This code might have some unrelated errors or bugs because I half finished making something then undid it and quit :P

Comment: Do you know anything about heap and stack allocation? You didn't initialize your FileController. You must allocate it first!

Comment: Nope, I watched 73 tutorials in the past week, and It didn't tell me anything about it e.o
Do you mean 'FileOperations *FileController;' in mainwindow.h? do you mean I have to make it an object before turning it into a pointer? also, if i didnt initialize it, how did half of the functions still work :O

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, so it "works" but it may not work at all. Read about heap and stack and you should quickly understand what you're doing wrong.